# Go to a secific cell depending on a variable A(Variable)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is it possible to use a formula to take a result from A(line Number) where in (Line number). I want to provide a variable from somewhere else.

It would be something like:

I have 1 to 10 distributed on `A1` to `A10`. I can insert a number from 1 to 10 on Cell `B1`. On `A11` I want to `sum(A1:A"Variable on B1")`.

So if `B1 = 5` then `A11` will sum numbers in `A1:A5`, and if `B1 = 9` then `A11` will sum number in `A1:A9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=Indirect()` would work nicely for this. In `A11` put `=sum(Indirect("A1:A" & B1))`  Indirect turns text into a link to a cell or range. So if you put a 2 in `B1` you will get `Sum(A1:A2)`